# AngularJs + Checkbox Click Is Not Working + Appended Checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

In my JS code, I am appending checkbox as per the selection of dropdown element. If I am selecting a element from dropdown, then at the same inline I am creating a checkbox of same name and disabling the element from dropdown because already showing in checkbox.

This is used to render HighCharts. Now I am trying to uncheck / check the Checkbox and trying on-change function to execute one function but system is not calling that function.

Few snippets of code:

```
var add_bpx = '<label class="check_btn"><input id="box" type="checkbox" ng-model="'+element+'" ng-change="runCheckedBox()" checked name="'+element+'" '+element+'</label>';
$('#input_row').append(add_box);
```

Output:

```
<div class="input_row" id="input_row">
  <label class="check_btn">
    <input id="box" type="checkbox" ng-model="Box1" ng-change="runCheckedBox()" checked="" name="Box1">Box1
  </label>
  <label class="check_btn">
    <input id="box" type="checkbox" ng-model="Box2" ng-change="runCheckedBox()" checked="" name="Box2">Box2
  </label>
</div>
```

AngularJs:-

```
  $scope.runCheckedBox = function(){
    console.log('RunCheck Box executed'); 
  }
```

Here function is not calling.

Comment: With checkbox i think is better to use ng-click

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on a sample fiddle, can you check the controller?

```js
var elements = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var add_box = '<label class="check_btn"><input id="box" type="checkbox" ng-model="' + element + '" ng-change="runCheckedBox()" checked name="' + element + '" ' + element + '</label>';
    $('#input_row').append(add_box);
}

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.runCheckedBox = function(){
    console.log('RunCheck Box executed'); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="input_row" id="input_row"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey Huy, Thanks a lot for the reply... I tried your snippet code at Jsfiddle. But it is not working. Please have a look .. May be I missed something. JsfiddleLink : http://jsfiddle.net/rpatil/q54protv/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q54protv/1/.
In order for angularJS to work in JSFiddle, you have to choose "No wrap - in <body>" on the left select box.

Comment: Thanks Huy, I saw the new fiddle link. It is working now. But I am unable to implement this feature inside my html. You said like add NoWrap in body. But I am not able to do that. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would say is take a look at this:

["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542)

Your problem is that when you add the input, angular needs to compile it.
I would suggest rather than *adding* the checkboxes in your select handler, you add them **all** to the html up front using ng-repeat, and use a model variable together with ng-show to control which ones are visible.